# Можно ли разбить js файл на модули?

Tags: javascript, jquery, модульность

Всем привет. Пишу код который весьма громадный. Может я и что-то делаю не так, но пока все работает  и меня устраивает)) Проблема в том, что чем больше код тем менее он понятен и читабелен. Я бы хотел его разделить на несколько `.js` файлов и подключать при помощи импорта. Возможно ли такое? Если да то прошу объяснить, как это делать. Работал только с `js` и `jquery`. Особых навыков `JS` не имею. Так что прошу по порядку всё изложить, если не сложно.

Comment: А можно код????

Comment: Можно но не нужно ,код мой ничем не поможет ,конечно вы сможете мне подсказать как его уменьшить и более оптимизировать ,но меня щас волнует конкретный вопрос ,давайте не отвликатmься :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Добрый день! Для организации модульной структуры js, вы можете воспользоваться [requireJs](http://requirejs.org/), тогда подключение модулей будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
define([
  "jquery"
], function($){
  // use jquery
}
```

Для более приятного import/export можно использовать возможности js стандарта es6. Тут вам не обойтись без какого-нибудь сборщика, который будет транслировать es6 в es5 стандарт. Например, можно использовать gulp, webpack, grunt или любой другой + babel, es6fy, browserfy и т.д., тогда код будет выглядеть еще приятней:

```
import {$} from "../vendor/jquery";
```

Comment: спасибо большое да это то что я ищу )а что можете посоветов из сборщиков ?Я читал стотью модулей про webpack  но особо незнаю.И не сильно ли это скажется на проивдительности скрипта ?

Comment: У них есть свои преимущества. Вебпак, например, может livereload делать, а gulp, на мой взгляд, проще и наглядней. Можете попробовать Gulp + babel. Вот я тут для себя сделал небольшой template для таких проектов [frontend_gulp_template](https://bitbucket.org/Mikl_Zhdanov/frontend_gulp_template/commits/all)

Comment: Кроме requireJs существует еще SystemJS

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете jQuery, то можно подключить файл, используя [jQuery.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/):

```
$.getScript("imported_script.js", function(){
   alert("Скрипт загружен!");
});
```

Comment: а с помощью этого метода можно обращаться к переменным функциям загруженного файла ("скрипта")?

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день. Обратите внимание на такие библиотеки, как requireJS. О подключении писали выше. Также, можно писать на TypeScript и использовать стандартные модули ES6 через его import и export. Изучите паттерны проектирования, такие как: модуль, наблюдатель, медиатор, фасад. Это поможет вам структурировать код и писать более грамотные веб-приложения

Comment: Добрый день!Спасибо большое за советы на будущее .Благодарю обезательно поинтересуюсь такими деталями .Спасибо за человчность!